# Selenium Webdriver: how do respond on a prompt

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to set up a test for a webpage using Selenium WebDriver and Python. Therefore I start the Docker image *selenium/standalone-firefox*.

Within this test normally a JavaScript written prompt pops up and want to receive an entry prior I can click OK.

But how can I interact with this prompt and the OK button?

On Selenium IDE the recorder uses `answer on next prompt` for that. How to do this with Python-Selenium? If Python does not support an corresponding command, how do I get the needed information to do the same with the available commands?

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# connect to docker Selenium Server
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Remote(
   command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
   desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities()
)

driver.get("https://www.ecalc.ch/motorcalc.php?hacker&lang=en&weight=4500&calc=auw&motornumber=1&warea=60&elevation=300&airtemp=25&motor=hacker&type=2|a60-7xs_v4_28-pole&gear=1&propeller=apc_electric&diameter=18&pitch=10.0&blades=2&batteries=topfuel_light_4500mah_-_30/45c&s=8&esc=master_spin_160_pro&cooling=good")

print(driver.title)

driver.find_element_by_id("modalConfirmOk").click()

driver.find_element_by_name("btnCalculate").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("AddCSV").click()

????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must handle the prompt alert. Try it with:

```py
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("Your project name");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle using alert class in selenium.

```
#Switch the control to the Alert window
obj = driver.switch_to.alert

time.sleep(2)

#Enter text into the Alert using send_keys()
obj.send_keys('test')
```

refer this [link selenium](https://www.techbeamers.com/handle-alert-popup-selenium-python/)